# Two Forms In a HTML Document

Tags: php, html, forms, cakephp-2.1

I am having a form as below.

```
    <div class="container">
    <form method="post" action="index.php">
        <div id="rule">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span5">
                    <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" value="Rule Name"/>
                </div>
                <div class="span6">
                    <input type="text" class="input-xxlarge" value="Description"/>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div id="sel" class="select">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span1 offset2">
                    <p class="btn btn-danger">If</p>
                </div>
                <div class="span2">
                   <select class="span2" name="metrics">
                      <option value="bounce_rate">Bounce Rate</option>
                      <option value="location">Locations</option>
                      <option value="social_media">Social Media</option>
                      <option value="search">Search</option>
                      <option value="visits">Visitors</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="span1">
                  <select name="conditions" class="span2">
                       <option value=">">></option>
                       <option value="<"><</option>
                       <option value=">=">>=</option>
                       <option value="<="><=</option>
                        <option value="=">=</option>
                     </select>
                </div>
                <div class="span1 offset1">
                    <input type="text" name="percentage" class="input-small"/>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"> </div>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span1 offset2">
                    <p class="btn btn-danger">Period</p>
                </div>
                <div class="span3">
                    <div class="input-append date datepicker" data-date="12-02-2012" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
                      <input class="span2" size="16" type="text" value="12-02-2012" />
                      <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="span3">
                    <div class="input-append date datepicker" data-date="12-02-2012" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
                      <input class="span2" size="16" type="text" value="12-02-2012" />
                      <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"> </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
        <div id="dyna"></div>
        <div id="end">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span1">
                    <p class="btn btn-danger">THEN</p>
                </div>
                <div class="span3">
                    <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" value="Statement" />
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span1">
                    <p class="btn btn-danger">ELSE</p>
                </div>
                <div class="span3">
                    <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" value="Statement" />
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <button class="span1 btn btn-success" type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
                <div class="span2 offset9">
                    <p class="btn btn-success input-small" id="addRule">Add Rule </p>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>     
</div>
```

I have included a button 'Add Rule' to create a dynamic elements within the above . So I used a javascript for creating dynamic elements as same of above.
The javascript as below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.datepicker').datepicker();
(function(){
    var i = 0;
    $("#addRule").live('click',function(){
        ++i;
        var $ctrl = $('<div id="'+ i +'" class="select"><div class="row"><div class="span1 offset2"><button class="btn btn-danger">If</button></div><div class="span2"><select class="span2" name="metrics"><option value="bounce_rate">Bounce Rate</option><option value="location">Locations</option><option value="social_media">Social Media</option><option value="search">Search</option><option value="visits">Visitors</option></select></div><div class="span1"><select name="conditions" class="span2"><option value=">">></option><option value="<"><</option><option value=">=">>=</option><option value="<="><=</option><option value="=">=</option></select></div><div class="span1 offset1"><input type="text" name="percentage" class="input-small"/></div><div class="span2 offset1"><button class="btn btn-danger remove" id="'+ i +'">Remove</button></div><div class="clearfix"> </div></div><br /><div class="row"><div class="span1 offset2"><p class="btn btn-danger">Period</p></div><div class="span3"><div class="input-append date datepicker" data-date="12-02-2012" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy"><input class="span2" size="16" type="text" value="12-02-2012" /><span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span></div></div><div class="span3"><div class="input-append date datepicker" data-date="12-02-2012" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy"><input class="span2" size="16" type="text" value="12-02-2012" /><span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span></div></div><div class="clearfix"> </div></div></div>');
        $("#dyna").append($ctrl);
        $('.datepicker').datepicker();
}); 
}) ();

(function(){
    $(".remove").live('click',function(){
        var remDiv = $(this).attr('id');
        //var questionList = "questionList"+remQ;
        $("#" + remDiv).remove();
});

}) ();
```

So I wanna get the values once i click the submit button. Is it correct way what i am using only a form for fetching the data or am i create two forms separately? So how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to create a second form if you are inserting the new elements into the existing form and as long as they have different names from any existing inputs you want to receive.

You can create a second form if you want different submit buttons for the two different collections of input data.

Comment: Actaully I am inserting same elements and I wanna get separate data for every dynamic insertion.